# Hive Updates Efficiency (Version 0.14)

Tags: hadoop, hive

**How can Hive efficiently handle the updates on columns which are not partitioned?**

Suppose I want to update a row for a specific transactionid (not partitioned), how will Hive handle it internally. From what I understand Hive will first search for this (which is slow) and then update that particular partition (if any) where this particular row containing this transactionid is stored. 
Even though this will provided an abstraction to the user to update data but will it really be efficient to perform a lot of updates ?

Comment: Does hive even support indiviual row update ?

Comment: From version 0.14, Hive has started supporting updates. Check more details here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions

Comment: why on earth you would wish to update a SINGLE row on Hadoop using Hive?

Comment: i don't wish to..i am just interested in knowing how will those be handled internally

Answer (score 0):

row level updates may not be efficient in hadoop as hadoop is designed for large data processing. However from Hive version 0.14 supports row level updates on Hive tables that support ACID. Check Hive tutorial for further details on how to implement row level updates.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Update